# How to alternate the auto-clicking of 2 buttons by ClassName in a repeating period of time?

Tags: javascript, userscripts, tampermonkey

I'm trying to make an autoclicker which alternates between buttons 1 and 2, each hour.
But i'm having problems getting the classname with parent and child relation on the code for make the click in the correct option.

The buttons are like:

```
<button class="trick__btn js-cta" data-door="1">Open</button>
<button class="trick__btn js-cta" data-door="2">Open</button>
```

I've try to use `document.querySelectorAll` to get that specific classname and click on it, but it's not effecting the page:

```
var classes = document.querySelectorAll('trick__btn js-cta" data-door="1');
var Rate = classes[0];
Rate.click();
```

Comment: Your query string is invalid `trick__btn js-cta" data-door="1`

Comment: Didn't you submit this source code in a different question a few hours ago....

Comment: any suggestions to repair it ? I still pretty noobie on javascript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Many things:

1. Your CSS selector was wrong:  classes need a `.`prepended and attributes are selected as shown below.
2. You need a way to remember the last button -- especially if the page reloads.  Below,  I use a `sessionStorage` variable.
3. You *probably* need to wait for the buttons to load.  One way for that is to use `waitForKeyElements()`.

Here is **a complete working script** that shows the process:

```js
// ==UserScript==
// @name     _Click Alternate buttons
// @match    *://YOUR_SERVER.COM/YOUR_PATH/*
// @require  https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js
// @require  https://gist.github.com/raw/2625891/waitForKeyElements.js
// @grant    GM_addStyle
// @grant    GM.getValue
// ==/UserScript==
//- The @grant directives are needed to restore the proper sandbox.
/* global $, waitForKeyElements */
/* eslint-disable no-multi-spaces */

waitForKeyElements (".trick__btn.js-cta[data-door='1']", startButtonClicking, true);

function startButtonClicking () {
    clickAlternateButton ();  // Initial. Comment out to wait for 1st click.

    //  5000 = 5 seconds. For 1 hour, use: 3600000.
    setInterval (clickAlternateButton, 5000);
}

function clickAlternateButton () {
    var zButton;

    if (sessionStorage.TM_button_1_WasLastClicked === "true") {
        sessionStorage.TM_button_1_WasLastClicked = false;
        zButton = $(".trick__btn.js-cta[data-door='2']");
    }
    else {
        sessionStorage.TM_button_1_WasLastClicked = true;
        zButton = $(".trick__btn.js-cta[data-door='1']");
    }
    console.log ("Clicking a button", zButton.attr("data-door"), new Date() );
    clickNode (zButton);
}

function clickNode (jNode) {
    var clickEvent  = document.createEvent ('MouseEvents');
    clickEvent.initEvent ('click', true, true);
    jNode[0].dispatchEvent (clickEvent);
}
```

Comment: It work thanks @BrockAdams I've add a refresh function at the beginning to  refresh every 59:57 minutes to make the rest of the code work in the webpage 

`$(document).ready(function(){
    setInterval(function(){ reload_page(); },3573000);
 });

 function reload_page()
 {
    window.location.reload(true);
 }`